# What is wrong with the pointer usage in this simple program?

Tags: c

I'm using VS 2010 Express, and I'm on Win Vista.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int somefunc(char *p);
int main()
{
    char *p = 0;
    int x;
    x = somefunc (p);
    printf("%c", *p);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
int somefunc(char *p)
{
    char y = '4';
    p = &y;
    return 2;
}
```

After I return to `main()`, I see the following in the autos window for p:

`p  0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>`

Anyone know why? It's as if the pointer is being treated as an automatic variable.

Btw, the x was just to create a similar condition to the same problem I was having in a larger program, but I don't think people want to sift through all of that code just to get to the meat of the problem, which is displayed here.

Comment: It works fine when I move the body of `somefunc()` into main.

Comment: `somefunc(&p);...int somefunc(char **p){... *p = &y;...}...`

Comment: "and I'm on Win Vista" - I feel for you :-) Don't get me wrong, Windows is okay, it's just that MS seems to suffer a good/bad release cycle mentality, and Vista was one of the downers.

Comment: By the way, http://powerfield-software.com/?p=251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` in `main()` is a null pointer.  It is passed by value to `somefunc()`, but that means that the value in the variable `p` in the function is a copy of the value in `p` in the main program, not a pointer to `p` itself.  You change what the copy of `p` in the function points at; fortunately, it doesn't change what's in the main program.

Then you try to print what's at the position pointed to by the null pointer; this is undefined behaviour and programs typically crash.

If you had managed to change `p` in the main program, it would be pointing to an automatic local variable in `somefunc()` that would be out of scope — which is more undefined behaviour.

This would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somefunc(char **p);

int main(void)
{
    char *p = 0;
    int x = somefunc(&p);
    printf("%c\n", *p);
    return 0;
}

int somefunc(char **p)
{
    static char y = '4';
    *p = &y;
    return 2;
}
```

There are many other, possibly better, ways to make this work too.

---

> I'm still confused on what `*p = &y;` means. If `p` in `somefunc` is a pointer to the pointer `p`, let's say `p2` is a pointer to `p1`, then `*p2 = p1`, so `*p2` is `p1`, which stores `&y`? Is that the correct way of thinking about this?

Basically, yes.  First, let's rewrite the code to disambiguate the use of `p`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *p1 = 0;
    int x = somefunc(&p1);
    printf("%c\n", *p1);
    return 0;
}

int somefunc(char **ppc)
{
    static char y = '4';
    *ppc = &y;
    return 2;
}
```

The variable `ppc` is a pointer to pointer to `char` (hence the name `ppc` — not a name I'd normally use except for pedagogical purposes).  I'll also rename `p` in `main()` to `pq1`, and introduce `char *p2;` in `somefunc()` which is a pointer to `char`.

Revising your comment in terms of these variables:

> I'm still confused on what `*ppc = &y;` means. If `ppc` in `somefunc()` is a pointer to the pointer `p1` in `main()`, then let's say `ppc` is a pointer to `p1`, then `*ppc = p1`, so `*ppc` is `p1`, which stores `&y`? Is that the correct way of thinking about this?

And that strongly shows that you're thinking is correct.  One of the design guidelines for the C type nomemclature was that if you write:

```
SomeType *stp;
```

then `*stp` represents a value of type `SomeType` — declaration mimics use.

Now, with `ppc`, the declaration is `char **ppc;` and the declaration mimics use rule means that `**ppc` is a value of type `char`.  Consequently, it means that `*ppc` is a value of type `char *`.  It means that when you write to `*ppc`, you are modifying the space that `ppc` points at, and it points at the address of `char *p1;` in `main()` in the sample code.

Comment: What is the difference between `char **p` and `char p` for the function parameter? Why can I pass and modify an array without having to return it, but I have to with a pointer? They are both addresses.

Comment: JL, heads up, call to `somefunc` should pass `&p` rather than `p`.

Comment: Did you mean `char p` or `char *p`?  Note the recently added `&` to the function call.  `char **p` means that `p` is a pointer to a `char *`.  `*p` is the `char *`; in context, it means that `p` in the function contains the pointer to `char *p`, so the function can modify the value in `p` in the main program — ouch; it is hard having two variables with the same name!  `char *` is simply a pointer to some character — or no character since `p` in `main` is initially null.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks — I noticed that and fixed it while typing up my prior comment (before seeing yours, but thanks anyway).

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 No, an array is not "an address". An array is a pile of objects. For various practical reasons, arrays decay into pointers to their first element in some contexts, but that doesn't mean that arrays are pointers. Also, you still seem not to get the difference between a pointer and the object it points to.

Comment: I'm still confused on what `*p = &y;` means. If p in somefunc is a pointer to the pointer p, let's say p2 is a pointer to p1, then *p2 = p1, so *p2 is p1, which stores &y? Is that the correct way of thinking about this?

Answer (score 4):

You are modifying `p` in `somefunc` but this won't modify `p` in `main`. You probably need to pass a pointer to `p` if you want to modify its value.

Comment: I thought the idea of a pointer is that when you pass it to a function, you can modify it's value and then use it once you return? What is going on? When an array is passed to a function, the address is getting passed, just like a pointer, and we're free to edit it and not have to use it as the return value.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050, you're absolutely correct but, when the thing you want to modify is actually already a pointer, you need a pointer to the pointer :-)

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 here you just passed null pointer.It point nothing any address and how can you hold any value in that? So first need to point it any address and change that value. So you have to pass as pointer to pointer (`&p`)and in function(`char **p`) point the address by `*p=&y.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 you can modify its *pointed object,* but not the pointer itself. Pointers are not references -- they are *not* special in that you can't magically pass a pointer to a function and have it modified, it's only the object it points to that can be written. (Think about what a pointer is, and it will make sense.)

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: it's exactly the same reason `int i = 5; somefunc(5); printf("%d", i);` ... `void somefunc(int i) {i = 6;}` prints 5.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Jonathan's answer, for your question

> What is the difference between char **p and char p for the function parameter? Why can I pass and modify an array without having to return it, but I have to with a pointer? They are both addresses.

In *C*, there's no pass by reference, there's only pass by value i.e. any argument passed to a function is copied to its parameters, but can't be made to refer to the original. This is the reason functions like `swap` is implemented using pointers. Example

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
   int t = *x;
   *x = *y;
   *y = t;
}

int a = 0, b = 1;
swap(&a, &b);
```

Here `&a` is a pointer whose value is copied onto `x`, thus it is pass by value (sometimes, incorrectly, called pass by reference). So I should be able to do the same when modifying pointers too, right?

Nope. Since a pointer is already pointing to something, making it point another thing needs another level of indirection. An analogy would be: you know somewhere a direction sign is pointing towards your home, by just knowing where it's pointing to (home), would you be able to change the direction it's pointing? No, you'd have to know where the sign is to go there and make it point in another direction.

Likewise, say if a variable lives at level 0 then to edit it, we go to a level further i.e. level 1 to modify it (from outside). This concept can be applied recursively; so to edit a variable at level 1, we've to go to level 2 to modify them from outside and so on. Pictorially

```
         type:          int*         int         int*
variable name:          ptr           a          pptr
                      --------     -------     --------
        value:        | 1000 | --> |  1  | <-- | 1000 |
                      --------     -------     --------
      address:          2000        1000         2400
```

Notice that `pptr` can't change where `ptr` is pointing to since `pptr` too is pointing at what `ptr` is pointing at `a`. However

```
      int**        int*         int
      pptr         ptr           a
    --------     --------     -------
    | 2000 | --> | 1000 | --> |  1  |
    --------     --------     -------
      2400         2000        1000
```

now `pptr` (`int**`) is in a position to modify where `ptr` (`int*`) is pointing to. If you'd to modify `pptr` then you to go another level higher `ppptr` (`int***`) and so on.